# How can I find out if a SAP MII transaction provides an output property of a given name?

Tags: workbench, sap-mii

In a SAP MII transaction, I use a *Dynamic Transaction Call* to call a subtransaction. I would like to check if this transaction provides an output parameter of a given name. (Not if its value exists but if the property itself is available.)

Is there any way to do this apart from blindly linking to the expected property, defining `ThrowOnLinkError = true` and catching a possible exception?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can: use `Catch` blocks and then add `Assignment` block where you assing local variable: `ThrowOnLinkError = true` or log it by adding a `Tracer` block depending on how you want to receive the error.

[image: <code>Assignment</code> block]
[image: <code>Tracer</code> block]

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this is precisely what I said I did not want to do...